# How to setup Docker container with Redis (Stack) server to use a configuration file?

Tags: docker, redis, configuration, dockerfile

I need to run a Docker container with Redis Stack pre-configured to use a config file and ACL file. My Dockerfile (placed in the same folder as the `redis.conf` and `users.acl`) is as follows:

```
FROM redis/redis-stack:latest
WORKDIR /db
COPY redis.conf ./redis-stack.conf
COPY users.acl ./users.acl
ENV PORT=6379
EXPOSE 6379
```

I run the container with `docker run -p 6379:6379 --mount type=volume,source=database-vol,target=/db,readonly=0 container_name`, using a named volume.

After this, the Redis server starts, but instead of using these config/acl files, uses a default `.conf`, seemingly placed in the `/opt/redis-stack/etc` folder. Using `COPY` in the Dockerfile to place my files in that folder instead doesn't help: the files are there, but the server doesn't use them: `redis-cli` command `acl list` returns the default user only, meaning my `.conf` file is ignored.

I understand there is a possibility to pass arguments in `docker run` with `--env REDIS_ARGS=""`, but I am not sure if/which arguments would setup the configuration file.

How do I point the redis server in the container to use my files? Is it possible for them to be in an arbitrary location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trying, figured it out. `redis-stack-server` (or `redis-server` if you're using the non-stack image) executable is already configured in `PATH`, so it's possible to `CMD` or `RUN` it easily from the Dockerfile.

To run the server with the given config file, I use `CMD [ "redis-stack-server", "redis.conf" ]`. The full Dockerfile is then as follows:

```
FROM redis/redis-stack:latest 

WORKDIR /usr/local/db

COPY redis.conf ./redis.conf
COPY users.acl ./users.acl

ENV PORT=6379
EXPOSE 6379

CMD [ "redis-stack-server", "redis.conf" ]
```

This will start the Redis Stack server with the given configuration, as well users provided in the ACL file.

Answer (score 0):

Location of acl file is configured with [aclfile](https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/1571907ea02020a829fca63806780c6f3ecf65a0/redis.conf#L1025) parameter.

So, based on your Dockerfile, adding `--env REDIS_ARGS="envfile /db/users.acl"` should do the trick.

Somehow related, [pass arguments via the command line](https://redis.io/docs/manual/config/#passing-arguments-via-the-command-line)

Comment: Thank you, but this isn't going to work. As stated, the redis stack server isn't using my config file at all. I would like to set the ACL file, among many other things, in the config file speicifically. For that, I need to point the server to start with my config file, which it currently doesn't, and I don't know how to make it.